# MySQL - Manual CSV Import - Column Data Type Errors

Tags: mysql, csv, mysqlimport, csv-import

I am trying to import a COVID-19 dataset into MySQL Workbench manually on MySQL 8.0 with CREATE TABLE and then LOAD DATA INFILE.

For columns such as hospital patients per million for example, the data varies in number of digits (up to 8) and number of decimal places (up to 3).

Also, data in other columns such as new cases has negative figures (when number of new cases starts falling compared to previous records).

When I run the below CREATE TABLE query, the table would populate with all columns. Then when I import the CSV file with LOAD DATA INFILE, column data type "decimal" would keep giving me errors such as Error 1366 incorrect decimal value at row 1.

So I changed it to "float" and it gave me Error 1265 data truncated at row 1. Now I've changed it to "double", as another Stack Overflow user had suggested, and still get Error 1265 Data truncated at row 1.

Here is the CREATE TABLE query:

```
CREATE TABLE covid_deaths (
    iso_code text,
    continent text,
    location text,
    date date,
    population bigint,
    total_cases int,
    new_cases int,
    new_cases_smoothed double,
    total_deaths int,
    new_deaths int,
    new_deaths_smoothed double,
    total_cases_per_million double,
    new_cases_per_million double,
    new_cases_smoothed_per_million double,
    total_deaths_per_million double,
    new_deaths_per_million double,
    new_deaths_smoothed_per_million double,
    reproduction_rate double,
    icu_patients int,
    icu_patients_per_million double,
    hosp_patients int,
    hosp_patients_per_million double,
    weekly_icu_admissions double,
    weekly_icu_admissions_per_million double,
    weekly_hosp_admissions double,
    weekly_hosp_admissions_per_million double
);
```

Here is the LOAD DATA INFILE query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'CovidDeaths.csv' 
    INTO TABLE covid_deaths 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

First 3 columns and first 3 rows of CSV (26 columns and 85,171 rows):

```
    iso_code, continent, location, date, population, total_cases
    AFG, Asia, Afghanistan, 2020-02-24, 38928341, 1
    AFG, Asia, Afghanistan, 2020-02-25, 38928341, 1
```

Additional info:

I tried importing all "double" columns above with the data type "varchar" instead, and it **worked**. However, when I use ORDER BY DESC it would give me e.g. 99.4 followed by 887.2, as it was ordering descending by characters (9 before 8) rather than the numeric values (887.2 is bigger than 99.4).

So I need a numeric data type rather than varchar, in order to **analyze** the data. But I'm just mentioning that when I used "varchar" to import, all 85,171 rows were imported perfectly, and I was able to query the data as well.

My CSV file is already in the working directory.

Using the Table Data Import Wizard finishes with 0 rows affected (i.e. no data imported except the column titles). This is why I am using the CREATE TABLE then LOAD DATA INFILE route instead.

My data had a header row (column titles), so I thought this could also be a problem. I included IGNORE 1 ROWS but it didn't help. I also removed the header row from the CSV file, leaving only the data. This didn't help either.

secure-file-priv is turned off and I have privileges to edit my.ini if required.

I am new on Stack Overflow, I have done some research, but I apologize if my question is still not up to standard. Please let me know if any additional information is required. Thank you and have a pleasant day.

Comment: Can you post the first couple of lines of the CSV file?

Comment: @Barmar How may I post CSV file lines here?

Comment: Paste them into a code block.

Comment: @Barmar Done, thank you. Hope this helps. Need more data?

Comment: Do you really need double when int would probably do (or bigint) or decimal? And if you can successfully load as varchar I would do that to a staging table then once you have in mysql push into final table.

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes, I can successfully load varchar. I'll see if I can do that staging table then final table route. Thank you for the suggestion.

I had stated in my post that "decimal" didn't work. I need "decimal" for columns with decimal figures as I prefer to be precise. "double" and "float" didn't work either.

"bigint" for population possibly worked, but I would never know if it worked, as when I run LOAD DATA INFILE, another column later would pop an error and stop the import.

Comment: Where can I get source data?

Comment: @P.Salmon Here --> https://ourworldindata.org/covid-deaths

Comment: Guys, meanwhile, I'm going ahead with the import using "varchar" wherever I get an error. Then, I intend using CAST while performing analysis. But I would surely appreciate a solution for the above.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't show any of the double columns that are causing the errors.

Comment: @Barmar Why? I am using exactly this data. All columns except the "text" columns in the beginning result in errors whether I use "double", "float" or "decimal". I couldn't even import the "int" or "bigint" columns. I had to use "varchar" for everything after the date column.

Comment: I thought the problem was only the columns with `DECIMAL` datatype, and you changed them to `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE`, so the `INT` and `BIGINT` columns were working.

Answer (score 0):

My first observation is that the published table does not contain all the columns in the file (at least from todays version)--it needs to. Second the file providers don't tell you the datatypes to use , which is a bit naughty. I would download the xslx file and examine that to determine appropriate datatypes.

If you don't want all the columns in the data you can discard by pushing them to user defined variables. This also a useful way of finding and/or transforming read columns see the section Input Preprocessing https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html.

The following loaded the columns I asked for

```
DROP TABle if exists covid_deaths;
CREATE TABLE covid_deaths (
iso_code    varchar(20),
continent   varchar(20),
location    varchar(50),
date    varchar(20),
total_cases varchar(20),
new_cases   varchar(20),
new_cases_smoothed  varchar(20),
total_deaths    varchar(20),
new_deaths  varchar(20),
new_deaths_smoothed varchar(20),
total_cases_per_million varchar(20),
new_cases_per_million   varchar(20),
new_cases_smoothed_per_million  varchar(20),
total_deaths_per_million    varchar(20),
new_deaths_per_million  varchar(20),
new_deaths_smoothed_per_million varchar(20),
reproduction_rate   varchar(20),
icu_patients    varchar(20),
icu_patients_per_million    varchar(20),
hosp_patients   varchar(20),
hosp_patients_per_million   varchar(20),
weekly_icu_admissions   varchar(20),
weekly_icu_admissions_per_million   varchar(20),
weekly_hosp_admissions  varchar(20),
weekly_hosp_admissions_per_million  varchar(20),
total_tests varchar(20),
new_tests   varchar(20),
total_tests_per_thousand    varchar(20),
new_tests_per_thousand  varchar(20),
new_tests_smoothed  varchar(20),
new_tests_smoothed_per_thousand varchar(20),
positive_rate   varchar(20),
tests_per_case  varchar(20),
tests_units varchar(20),
total_vaccinations  varchar(20),
people_vaccinated   varchar(20),
people_fully_vaccinated varchar(20),
total_boosters  varchar(20),
new_vaccinations    varchar(20),
new_vaccinations_smoothed   varchar(20),
total_vaccinations_per_hundred  varchar(20),
people_vaccinated_per_hundred   varchar(20),
people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred varchar(20),
total_boosters_per_hundred  varchar(20),
new_vaccinations_smoothed_per_million   varchar(20),
new_people_vaccinated_smoothed  varchar(20),
new_people_vaccinated_smoothed_per_hundred  varchar(20),
stringency_index    varchar(20),
population_density  varchar(20),
median_age  varchar(20),
aged_65_older   varchar(20),
aged_70_older   varchar(20),
gdp_per_capita  varchar(20),
extreme_poverty varchar(20),
cardiovasc_death_rate   varchar(20),
diabetes_prevalence varchar(20),
female_smokers  varchar(20),
male_smokers    varchar(20),
handwashing_facilities  varchar(20),
hospital_beds_per_thousand  varchar(20),
life_expectancy varchar(20),
human_development_index varchar(20),
population  varchar(20),
excess_mortality_cumulative_absolute    varchar(20),
excess_mortality_cumulative varchar(20),
excess_mortality    varchar(20),
excess_mortality_cumulative_per_million varchar(20)
);

LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\Program Files\\MariaDB 10.4\\data\\sandbox\\owid-covid-data.csv' 
    INTO TABLE covid_deaths 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS
     (iso_code,
    continent,
    location,
    date,
    population ,
    total_cases,
     @new_cases ,
    @new_cases_smoothed ,
    @total_deaths ,
    @new_deaths ,
    @new_deaths_smoothed ,
    @total_cases_per_million ,
    @new_cases_per_million ,
    @new_cases_smoothed_per_million ,
    @total_deaths_per_million ,
    @new_deaths_per_million ,
    @new_deaths_smoothed_per_million ,
    @reproduction_rate ,
    @icu_patients ,
    @icu_patients_per_million ,
    @hosp_patients ,
    @hosp_patients_per_million ,
    @weekly_icu_admissions ,
    @weekly_icu_admissions_per_million ,
    @weekly_hosp_admissions ,
    @weekly_hosp_admissions_per_million ,
    @total_tests    ,
    @new_tests  ,
    @total_tests_per_thousand   ,
    @new_tests_per_thousand ,
    @new_tests_smoothed ,
    @new_tests_smoothed_per_thousand    ,
    @positive_rate  ,
    @tests_per_case ,
    @tests_units    ,
    @total_vaccinations ,
    @people_vaccinated  ,
    @people_fully_vaccinated    ,
    @total_boosters ,
    @new_vaccinations   ,
    @new_vaccinations_smoothed  ,
    @total_vaccinations_per_hundred ,
    @people_vaccinated_per_hundred  ,
    @people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred    ,
    @total_boosters_per_hundred ,
    @new_vaccinations_smoothed_per_million  ,
    @new_people_vaccinated_smoothed ,
    @new_people_vaccinated_smoothed_per_hundred ,
    @stringency_index   ,
    @population_density ,
    @median_age ,
    @aged_65_older  ,
    @aged_70_older  ,
    @gdp_per_capita ,
    @extreme_poverty    ,
    @cardiovasc_death_rate  ,
    @diabetes_prevalence    ,
    @female_smokers ,
    @male_smokers   ,
    @handwashing_facilities ,
    @hospital_beds_per_thousand ,
    @life_expectancy    ,
    @human_development_index    ,
    @population ,
    @excess_mortality_cumulative_absolute   ,
    @excess_mortality_cumulative    ,
    @excess_mortality   ,
    @excess_mortality_cumulative_per_million    
     );
    

select count(*) from covid_deaths;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   242447 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.339 sec)
```

EDIT example with empty or null values

```
id,val1,val2
1,38.0,1
2,null,1
3,,1
4,48.666666666666664,1

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
create table t
(id int auto_increment primary key , val1 decimal(10,2),val2 int);

LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\Program Files\\MariaDB 10.1\\data\\sandbox\\data.txt'
    INTO TABLE t
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS
     (id,@val1,val2)
     set val1 = case when @val1 = 'null' or @val1 = '' then null else @val1 end;
     
    
select * from t;

+----+-------+------+
| id | val1  | val2 |
+----+-------+------+
|  1 | 38.00 |    1 |
|  2 |  NULL |    1 |
|  3 |  NULL |    1 |
|  4 | 48.67 |    1 |
+----+-------+------+
4 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: (1/2) Thank you for your reply @P.Salmon! I split the original file into 2 CSV files, one with only the columns I specified above, the other one with the rest of the columns. I did this as I also wanted to perform JOINs (I'm doing a portfolio project). Your analysis is valid, but that is not the case here (my fault, I did not mention my separating the files from the original dataset).

Comment: (2/2) I think I have found the problem when importing another file for another project. The errors in 'decimal' (incorrect value), 'float' (import truncated) etc. happened in the rows where the field was blank (null). So how do I allow the import of nulls in my script for specific columns? Thank you so much @P.Salmon once again for your detailed help!

Comment: Also, as I mentioned, "varchar" did work for me, and it allowed me to import all the rows without issue. The whole problem is I don't want to have to use "varchar". I want to import numeric data as numeric / int / bigint / decimal / float etc. so I can actually analyze the data without having to CAST multiple columns every time. It gets messy when I need to compound CAST with MAX of one column divided by another column, you get the idea. Thanks for your help @P.Salmon

Comment: There is a section in the manual 'Handling of NULL values varies according to the FIELDS and LINES options in use:' which may be worth a look. I'm not clear what you mean by null since null is not the same as empty or blank and could be \N. Anyway now you have a clearer understanding at should be possible to mock create representative sample data.

Comment: Please see edit for a much simplified version of what I think your problems is and a resolution using input pre processing

Comment: This unfortunately did not solve my problem, as I have too many columns in place of 'val1' and in any case, even where I tried with any one column, I still get the Error 1366 Incorrect decimal value at row 1. I sincerely thank you for all your help and edits, I upvoted but I don't have enough reputation. Thanks again and best wishes.